# Moq an interface and setting up a mock

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, moq, xunit.net

I have an Interface to check vowel and to return a char as

```
public interface IVowChecker
{
    bool VowCheck(char a);
    char ReturnChar(int n);
    Student GetStudentById(int n);
}
```

It's concrete class implementation

```
public class VowChecker:IVowChecker
{
    public bool VowCheck(char a)
    {
        if (a == 'a' || a == 'A')
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public char ReturnChar(int n)
    {
        return (char)n;
    }
    public Student GetStudentById(int n)
    {
        var list = new []
        {
            new Student{RollNo=1,Name="A"},
            new Student{RollNo=2,Name="B"},
            new Student{RollNo=3,Name="C"},
            new Student{RollNo=4,Name="D"},
            new Student{RollNo=5,Name="E"},
            new Student{RollNo=6,Name="F"},
        };

        var student = from i in list
                      where i.RollNo == n
                      select i;
        return student.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And a service using this VowChecker

```
public class MyCharService
{
    private readonly IVowChecker _checker;

    public MyCharService(IVowChecker checker)
    {
        _checker = checker;
    }
    public bool CheckInput(char a)
    {
        return _checker.VowCheck(a);
    }
    public char ReturnChar(int a)
    {
        return _checker.ReturnChar(a);
    }
    public Student GetStudentById(int n)
    {
        return _checker.GetStudentById(n);
    }
}
```

I am using Xunit testing framework for unit testing and Moq library.
My unit test code is

```
public class MyCharServiceShould
{
    ...

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(65)]
    [InlineData(68)]
    public void BeAbleToReturnChar(int n)
    {
        var service = new Mock<IVowChecker>();

        service.Setup(i => i.ReturnChar(n)).Returns('A');
        var obj = new MyCharService(service.Object);
        var result = obj.ReturnChar(n);

    }
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(2)]
    public void BeAbleToRetrieveStudent(int n)
    {
        var service = new Mock<IVowChecker>();
        service.Setup<Student>(i => i.GetStudentById(n)).Returns<Student>(f => (Student)f);
        var ob = new MyCharService(service.Object);
        var res = ob.GetStudentById(2);
        Assert.Equal(res.Name, "B");
    }
}
```

My Student class

```
public class Student
{
    public int RollNo{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have used a debugger in the last line of my test and checked the values of both the tests. For the 1st test I am expecting 'A' as the result and for the 2nd test I am expecting 'D' as the result. But in both the cases I am getting 'A' as the result. Can anyone kindly help me out where I am missing out the concept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the setup for `ReturnChar`

```
service.Setup(i => i.ReturnChar(n)).Returns('A');
```

says,

```
Whenever ReturnChar() is called, give an answer of 'A'
```

It ignores the input 'n' and just returns 'A'. If you want it to return a different character for each test you will need to tweak the setup.

Perhaps

```
mockService.Setup(mk => mk.ReturnChar(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(n => (char)n);
```

EDIT: Extension to show returning objects (and fixed syntax on previous answer)

```
public class Student
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IService
{
  Student FindStudentById(int id);
}

[TestMethod]
public void FindStudents()
{
    var students = new[]
    {
        new Student {Id = 1, Name = "Mon" },
        new Student {Id = 2, Name = "Tue" },
        new Student {Id = 3, Name = "Wed" },
        new Student {Id = 4, Name = "Thu" },
    };

    var mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    mockService.Setup(mk => mk.FindStudentById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(id => students.First(s => s.Id == id));

    Assert.AreEqual("Wed", mockService.Object.FindStudentById(3).Name);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Could you please explain me a scenario. If I want to take roll number of the student as argument and i need to get that student object to be returned. How can I achieve that? Shall I use service.Setup(i=>i.GetStudentById(id)).Returns((StudentDetails)ob);

Comment: you will need to set up a list of students and a function find the student by Id. I'll edit the answer so show the general idea.

Comment: I have edited the question. I followed your procedure but in a bit different way. I am now facing issues for setting up the mock.

Comment: What issues? Looking at the updated question, there is no reference to `GetStudentById()`

Comment: I am facing issue while setting up the mock
service.Setup(i=>i.GetStudentById(n)).Returns(?)

Comment: What Issues? What have you tried? Note: The syntax in your comment is not correct. Have a look at the syntax in the example above.

Comment: In my MyCharService, when GetStudentById(2) is being called, it is giving me a exception as System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'MyTestWebApp.Core.Model.Student'.'  

Please refer the edited question in MyCharServiceShould

Comment: That is correct. One cannot convert an `int` to a `Student` which is what `f => (Student)f` attempts to do. The example I gave doesn't try to do that. Have you tried implementing the code from the example? Putting the list of students in the implementation doesn't help. It needs to be in the test

Comment: I understood your point. But assume the list is database. And, GetStudentById is one of the methods of my repository. I want to achieve the result in that scenario.

Comment: Whether the list is a database or not is moot for unit testing. We are setting up a mock (really a stub) for testing. It is the test code that needs to look up the student by id and return it. In the question, `GetStudentById()` is a method on `IVowChecker` and we are mocking the behaviour of `IVowChecker'.  The example given shows how to return a Student from the mock given a student id.  Anything further is a totally different question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012779/moq-unit-test-using-xunit-framework-and-testing-a-function-returning-an-object  . This question might be more clear to understand my requirement

Comment: Hi AlanT, please respond